# Question Unvisited/Visited Link colors

Tags: feature-request, design

Something I'm not liking about the main and beta sites...

In the question list the unvisited link colors are a lighter color while the visiting links are a darker color. My brain isn't making the connection correctly and I keep clicking on the darker links thinking they are new questions.

I'd prefer the opposite... Darker for unvisited links and lighter for visited links. This gives the new questions more visual importance in my opinion.

Can this be changed?

Answer (score 3):

I agree! I just tested what you are talking about right there in the Related area of the sidebar -->

Once this goes live and gets a redesign chances are everything will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with this. The colours are the wrong way around! +1 from me!